# Textarea change is not detected on onkeyup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Textarea change needs to be detected onkeyup event when page is loading. Textarea resizing is working fine but textarea is not detected onkeyup event when page is loaded.I tried following code.

```
<script>
    jQuery.each(jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]'), function () {
        var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;
        var resizeTextarea = function (el) {
            jQuery(el).css('height', 'auto').css('height', el.scrollHeight + offset);
        };
        jQuery(this).on('keyup input', function () {
            resizeTextarea(this);
        });
        jQuery(this).trigger('keyup');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can we have a _working demo_ with HTML ? Where have you placed your `<script>` ?

Answer (score 2):

try by running your code in  `window.onload`

```
window.onload=function(){
    jQuery.each(jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]'), function() {
      var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;
      var resizeTextarea = function(el) {
        jQuery(el).css('height', 'auto').css('height', el.scrollHeight + offset);
      };
      jQuery(this).on('keyup input', function() {
        resizeTextarea(this);
      });
      jQuery(this).trigger('keyup');
    });

    //trigger when modal showing
    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { 
        jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]').trigger('keyup');
    })

}
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p2n2vk9u/)

Comment: in Add Clause popup ?

Comment: ok in this case you need to trigger on modal showing for example. 

$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]').trigger('keyup');
})

Comment: can you show me example ? i don't think so this should be happen

Comment: jQuery(this).on('keyup input', function() {
        resizeTextarea(this);
      }).trigger('keyup'); you can also try

Comment: how to setTime out for trigger keyup events in your code?

Comment: setTimeout(function(){
jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]').trigger('keyup');

 }, 3000);

Comment: i added in code but it is not working can show on jsfiddle

Comment: I added your code in my program but it not working , $("#orderModal").modal("show"); 
  $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { 
     setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]').trigger('keyup'); }, 3000);
    });

Comment: wighout model it working , my problem is , when i click on button model is coming , in this model have textarea , this textarea not trigger keyup event ,

Comment: time-delay is working, but in your code i change 3000 to 100 then textarea is jembling or jenking or blinking , i don't want show that effect

Comment: why don't you add some kind of transition on resize ? jenking issue is not because of my code

Comment: when button click model is coming same time textarea trigger without any delay, how can i do?

Comment: hire me than i will help you :D well see full documentation here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Answer (score 1):

You shall execute jquery once the doc has finished loading.

Wrap it like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery.each(jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]'), function () {
        var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;
        var resizeTextarea = function (el) {
            jQuery(el).css('height', 'auto').css('height', el.scrollHeight + offset);
        };
        jQuery(this).on('keyup input', function () {
            resizeTextarea(this);
        });
        jQuery(this).trigger('keyup');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your html